# Relative XPath in scrapy selector

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the information in the table "Comissões a que pertence / pertenceu" from [here](http://www.parlamento.pt/DeputadoGP/Paginas/ActividadeDeputado.aspx?BID=4057&lg=XIII) using Scrapy.

Since the number of tables can change (and I want to extract the information for several equivalent pages), I first find the relevant section with

```
for node in response.xpath('//*[@class = "ARLabel TextBold"]'):
    texto = node.extract()
    if u'Comissões a que pertence' in texto:
        break
```

and then I was trying to find the part of the needed info through:

```
node.xpath('.//*[@class = "ARTabResultadosLinhaImpar"]')
```

but results in an empty list.

EDIT: removed /text()

Comment: But `node` is here a `text()` object? Shouldn't you go one level up again?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes you are right. I just removed text()

Comment: Please do not include your solution in an edit to your question. Instead, accept an existing answer (if applicable) or include your solution as a new answer. Questions should only contain the actual questions while answers should provide answers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Xpath:

```
//*[@class = "ARLabel TextBold" and contains(text(), 'Comissões a que pertence')]
```

Edit (to get table):

```
//table[@title='Tabela com as comissões a que pertence / pertenceu']
```

Mark answered if this solved your problem

Comment: I'm able to find this node. My problem is to find the table content using a relative XPath from the node.

Answer (score 0):

Relative xpath to the node you have selected can be done using `./` instead of `//`
see https://devhints.io/xpath
So you were almost there.
instead of `node.xpath('.//*[@class = "ARTabResultadosLinhaImpar"]')`

it should be

```
node.xpath('./*[@class = "ARTabResultadosLinhaImpar"]')
```